# Android: "onCreatedView" calls every time when going back and "setUserVisibleHint" is not called

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, fragmentmanager

In my android application I have a ViewPager and 5 fragments. I previously used `viewPager.setCurrentItem()` to navigate, but the requirement for navigation animation has changed; For an example in some fragments when a previous fragment is called, we were asked not to show going back (left to right animation), instead show the user their moving to the next fragment (right to left animation). For an example in some cases user has to insert the same data again and again so instead of creating new fragmnets for these, we re-used the existing ones we created- so when the `viewPager.setCurrentItem()` is calling a fragment in the back (ex: we are now in 20th fragment and we are calling 10th fragment) it goes back and shows left to right animation.

Now we are not using the `viewPager.setCurrentItem()` method to navigate, instead we use `FragmentTransaction`. However we did not remove the fragments from the ViewPager anyway, expecting to complete this with minimum work (we are at the end of project when this requirement appeared)

But when we use the `FragmentTransaction` we have a new issue now. When we come back the `onCreateView` of fragmnets are getting called all the time! This didn't happen when we were using `viewPager.setCurrentItem()`. Lot of our code which should run only once are in this `onCreateView`.

Another issue is `setUserVisibleHint()` is called only in first fragment and that is also only at the initial run! All of our code which should run every time the fragmnet is displayed is located in this method.

Below is an example code, which demonstrate our issue.

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    private ViewPager viewPager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        viewPager=(ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
        viewPager.setAdapter(new MyPagerAdapter2(getSupportFragmentManager()));
        viewPager.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                if (viewPager.getCurrentItem() == 0) {
                    return true;
                }

                if (viewPager.getCurrentItem() == 1) {
                    return true;
                }

                if (viewPager.getCurrentItem() == 2) {
                    return true;
                }

                if (viewPager.getCurrentItem() == 3) {
                    return true;
                }

                if (viewPager.getCurrentItem() == 4) {
                    return true;
                }

                return false;
            }
        });



    }

    private class MyPagerAdapter2 extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

        public MyPagerAdapter2(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int pos) {
            switch(pos) {

                case 0: return FirstFragment1.newInstance("FirstFragment_1");
                case 1: return SecondFragment1.newInstance("SecondFragment_1");
                case 2: return ThirdFragment1.newInstance("ThirdFragment_1");
                case 3: return FourthFragment1.newInstance("FourthFragment_1");
                case 4: return FifthFragment1.newInstance("FifthFragment_1");
                default: return FirstFragment1.newInstance("DefaultFragment_1");
            }
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return 1;
        }
    }

    public void setCurrentItem(int which) {
        if(viewPager != null && which >= 0 && which <= 4) {
            viewPager.setCurrentItem(which);
        }
    }
}
```

**FirstFragment1.java**

```
public class FirstFragment1 extends Fragment {

    TextView textView;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.first_frag_1, container, false);

        TextView tv = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tvFragFirst);
        tv.setText("FRAGMENT 01");

        textView=(TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        textView.setText("Fragment Name : - 01");

        Log.d("FRAGMENT_01", "ON_CREATE");

        Button button1 = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.nextButton);
        button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (getActivity() != null) {

                    FragmentManager fragmentManager=getFragmentManager();
                    FragmentTransaction transaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                    transaction.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.from_right, R.anim.to_left);
                    transaction.replace(R.id.firstFragment, new SecondFragment1());
                    transaction.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN);
                    transaction.addToBackStack(null);
                    transaction.commit();
                }
            }
        });

        return v;
    }

    public static FirstFragment1 newInstance(String text) {

        FirstFragment1 f = new FirstFragment1();
        Bundle b = new Bundle();
        b.putString("msg", text);

        f.setArguments(b);

        return f;
    }

    @Override
    public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser) {
        super.setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser);
        if (isVisibleToUser) {
            Activity a = getActivity();
            if (a != null) a.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LOCKED);

        //    textView.setText("Fragment Name : - 01");
            Log.d("FRAGMENT_01", "VISIBLE_HINT");

        }
    }

}
```

**SecondFragment1.java**

```
public class SecondFragment1 extends Fragment {

    TextView textView;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.second_frag_1, container, false);

        TextView tv = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tvFragSecond);
        tv.setText("FRAGMENT 03");

        textView=(TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        textView.setText("Fragment Name : - 02");

        Log.d("FRAGMENT_02", "ON_CREATE");

        Button button=(Button)v.findViewById(R.id.printButton);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                if(getActivity() != null) {

                    FragmentManager fragmentManager=getFragmentManager();
                    FragmentTransaction transaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                    transaction.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.from_right, R.anim.to_left);
                    transaction.replace(R.id.secondFrag, new FirstFragment1());
                    transaction.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN);
                    transaction.addToBackStack(null);
                    transaction.commit();
                }

            }
        });

        Button button1=(Button)v.findViewById(R.id.nextButton);
        button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (getActivity() != null) {

                    FragmentManager fragmentManager=getFragmentManager();
                    FragmentTransaction transaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                    transaction.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.from_right, R.anim.to_left);
                    transaction.replace(R.id.secondFrag, new ThirdFragment1());
                    transaction.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN);
                    transaction.addToBackStack(null);
                    transaction.commit();
                }
            }
        });

        return v;
    }

    public static SecondFragment1 newInstance(String text) {

        SecondFragment1 f = new SecondFragment1();
        Bundle b = new Bundle();
        b.putString("msg", text);

        f.setArguments(b);

        return f;
    }

    @Override
    public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser) {
        super.setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser);
        if(isVisibleToUser) {
            Activity a = getActivity();
            if(a != null) a.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LOCKED);

            Log.d("FRAGMENT_02","VISIBLE_HINT");


        }
    }

}
```

As you can see in our code, we use below to navigate between Fragments. (Below code shows navigating from first fragmnet to second)

```
FragmentManager fragmentManager=getFragmentManager();
                    FragmentTransaction transaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                    transaction.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.from_right, R.anim.to_left);
                    transaction.replace(R.id.firstFragment, new SecondFragment1());
                    transaction.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN);
                    transaction.addToBackStack(null);
                    transaction.commit();
```

Looking at our code, and considering we have added the `ViewPager` as well, how can we make sure that `onCreateView` is only called once and `setUserVisibleHint` is called everytime the fragment is displayed?

Answer (score 1):

there is challenges when using setUserVisibleHint is called.try viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(5); and use setMenuVisibility method and if you launch app on  any fragment by notification

```
@Override
public void setMenuVisibility(boolean menuVisible) {
    super.setMenuVisibility(menuVisible);
    if(menuVisible &&  isResumed()){
       // do  your work here
    }
    if(!isResumed()){
       // do your work when Activity is created 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Put all of your code which you want should not be called everytime in **onCreate()** method and the code which you want should be called everytime in **onCreateView()** method.

Comment: onCreate() is getting call every time that fragment is visible

Comment: when you swipe your viewpager it wont be called again and again.

Comment: I am not swiping the viewpager and I use button click to change fragment flow.